# When to use delay queue feature of Amazon SQS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I understand the concept of **delay queue** of Amazon SQS, but I wonder why it is useful.
What's the usage of SQS delay queue? 
Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One use case which i can think of is usage in distributed applications which have eventual consistency semantics. The system consuming the message may have an dependency like a co-relation identifier to be available and hence may need to wait for certain guaranteed duration of time before seeing the co-relation data. In this case, it makes sense for the message to be delayed for certain duration of time.

Comment: What is "co-relation identifier"?

Comment: Another use is when you process APIs that have a rate limit. I want to delay the message until there are some free resources again.

Answer (score 9):

Like you I was confused as to a use-case for delay queues, until I stumbled across one in my own work. My application needs to have an internal queue with each item waiting at least one minute between each check for completion.

So instead of having to manage a "last-checked-time" on every object, I just shove the object's ID into an SQS queue messagewith a delay time of 60 seconds, and my main loop then becomes a simple long-poll against the queue.

Answer (score 2):

A few off the top of my head:

1. Emails - Let's say you have a service that sends reminder emails triggered from queue messages. You'd have to delay enqueueing the message in that case.
2. Race conditions - Delivery delays can be used to overcome race conditions in distributed systems. For example, a service could insert a row into a table, and sends a message about its availability to other services. They can't use the new entry just yet, so you have to delay publishing the SQS message.
3. Handling retries - Sometimes if a message fails you want to retry with exponential backoffs. This requires re-enqueuing the message with longer delays.

I've built a suite of API's to make queue message scheduling easy. You can call our API's to schedule queue messages, cancel, edit, and check on the status of such messages. Think of it like a scheduler microservice.

[www.schedulerapi.com](https://schedulerapi.com)

If you are looking for a solution, let me know. I've built these schedulers before at work for delivering emails at high scale, so I have experience with similar use cases.

Comment: If you want to chat, I'm always available at schedulerapi@gmail.com as well.

Answer (score 1):

One use-case can be:

Think of a time critical expression like a scheduled equity trade order.

If one of your system is fetching all the order scheduled in next 60 minutes and putting them in queue (which will be fetched by another sub system).

If you send these order directly, then they will be visible immediately to process in queue and will be processed depending upon their order.

But most likely, they will not execute in exact time (Hour:Minute:Seconds) in which Customer wanted and this will impact the outcome.

So to solve this, what first sub system will do, it will add delay seconds (difference between current and execution time) so message will only be visible after that much delay or at exact time when user wanted.